# PGP support for mails

Tags: feature-request

Feature request :

Make a field per e-mail address where one's can enter a PGP key, so newletters and job alerts are encrypted (Facebook deos so e.g)

Comment: Well, I personally use mailbox.org, every incoming non-encrypted mail automatically gets encrypted with my pgp public key. Maybe try something like that if you're that concerned about safety? [I'm not affiliated with mailbox.org]

Comment: The problem of using third party service(s) is that the data is still unencrypted at SU/SO output. It can also do more hops to reach mailbox than your own inbox.

Comment: Indeed, and I'm all for privacy and security, but... I really don't see why PGP encrypting mails from stack would be helpful.

Comment: This question feels like it would be better off at https://meta.stackexchange.com/ as it would be something for the network as a whole rather than one particular site.

Comment: I don't think I have access to SE meta.

Comment: Yes, Yes you do.

Comment: Gotta move it then, thanks ^^